# LaTeX Error: File `tikzfill.image.sty' not found

Tags: tlmgr

when I build the tex document, the log show info:

```
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikz
librarytopaths.code.tex)))
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.sty
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/trimspaces/trimspaces.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbskins.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbskins.code.tex' version '6.0.4'

! LaTeX Error: File `tikzfill.image.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
```

I have tried to use this command to install this package `tikzfill.image`:

```
tlmgr install tikzfill.image
```

still did not fixed this issue. What should I do to fixed it?

Comment: Is this question also related to docker?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
tlmgr install tikzfill.image
```

you can't in general install individual files via `tlmgr`

```
$ tlmgr info tikzfill.image.sty
tlmgr: cannot find package tikzfill.image.sty, searching for other matches:

Packages containing `tikzfill.image.sty' in their title/description:

Packages containing files matching `tikzfill.image.sty':
tikzfill:
        texmf-dist/tex/latex/tikzfill/tikzfill.image.sty
```

shows that you need

```
tlmgr install tikzfill
```